# Form being redirected but elements not being posted in mobile web-pages built using jquery-mobile API

Tags: php, post

I am running into a strange problem. My form is being redirected to the desired page, but the form values are not being posted.

Here is the part code of HTML file:

```
<form id="frmUploadFile" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
     <input type="file" id="uplChooseFile" name="File" />
     <input type="hidden" id="hidFileIndex" name="FileIndex" value="1" />
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" />
```

Here is the part of code of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
   $('#btnUpload').on('click', function(){
     if($('#uplChooseFile').val()){ 
        $('#frmUploadFile').submit();
     }
   });
});
</script>
```

Now, the page is being redirected to `upload.php`, but the posted values are not visible.

Here is a part of code from `upload.php`:

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   echo 'Hello';
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES); echo '</pre>'; exit();
?>
```

And finally, here is the output from the browser:

[image: Output from browser]

Any help please?

**UPDATE**

Another problem is the `upload.php` does not show output by itself as soon as it is redirected to. I have to refresh the page by pressing `F5` to see the output. Could that be causing the problem?

**UPDATE 2**
The code above is a part of web-page built for mobile devices built using jquery-mobile API.

Comment: I think you can easily check for errors using the console, every browser is bundled with cool developer tools, that's the very first step I'd take. If it's some 500 error code or whatever, then it's the code itself. Also, let PHP log all errors to a file so you can check for fatal errors and warnings (I think a fatal error is the only way it could possibly print exclusively after a silly F5). And why are you exiting anyway?

Comment: Nothing abnormal in error logs. The log reports **Apache Success** for the PHP files in question. Let me check Developer Tools and see what it says. Anyways, do you see anything wrong with the code? I don't think this is a rocket science code.

Comment: Checked Developer Tools in IE and Chrome. No errors or warnings in there. Now I am real stuck.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, copied the code in another project and it works.

Comment: Found the problem. jquery-mobile.js is somehow culprit. Removing or commenting it solves the problem.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I didn't see anything wrong with the code either, that's why I'm like maybe it's something you didn't copy in this extract. In any case if you need the jquery-mobile-js file, load it only when the site is accessed by a mobile device, or maybe the loading order.

Comment: Removing the js file from the web-page have file uploader has done the trick for me, but at the expense of losing beautiful UI created by jquery-mobile. Now, I am manually replicating those looks with my own custom CSS to make the web-page look in harmony with other web-pages. I have reported the issue on forum.jquery.com. Let's see what solution do they have to offer.

Comment: That's great, I appreciate you reporting the issue, nowadays I hear people saying that reporting takes so much time and makes no difference at all, when it actually means everything. I'm sorry to hear you have to do all of that on your own, but I'm sure you'll be able to do it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The code was actually a part of web-page designed for mobile devices using `jquery-mobile-1.4.5.js` to render page elements to suit mobile environment. Debugging web-page led to conclusion that `jquery-mobile-1.4.5.js` was somehow interfering with file uploader's functionality. Removing the js file solved the problem.